# Having hard time scraping a cell with Cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape a cell from a table but I'm having a hard time and I'm probably doing something wrong because I get an empty result in the console(literally nothing).

**Here's the HTML:**

[image]

I'm trying to get the `<td class="center bold storing_1">1</td>`.

**Here's my code:**

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = 'MY URL';

rp(url)
.then(function(html) {

  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  console.log($('#table_results tbody tr:nth-child(1) td.center.bold.sorting_1')).text();

})
.catch(function(err) {
});
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is actually ok, I think you just have a few typos in it.

- You are parsing 'body' rather than 'html'
- You are reading .text() from the result of console.log() rather than the cheerio object ($).

If you try the code below it should work:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = 'MY URL';

rp(url).then(function(html) {
    $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log("Result:", $('#table_results tbody tr:nth-child(1) td.center.bold.sorting_1').text());
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", err);
});
```

Html I'm testing with:

**Test html**

```
<table id="table_results">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ajax-controller="community">
            <td class="center bold sorting_1">1</td>
            <td class="center bold sorting_1">2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Simple test setup:**

You can play around with this to see how editing the selector changes things:

```
const testHtml = 
`<table id="table_results">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ajax-controller="community">
        <td class="center bold sorting_1">1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`;

$ = cheerio.load(testHtml);
console.log("Result:", $('#table_results tbody tr:nth-child(1) td.center.bold.sorting_1').text());
```

Comment: I'd suggest you set up a test case using just html text and no need to download anything over http. I'll update the answer with the html I'm testing with, this might help you to compare your html against. I'm getting a result of "1", I suspect this is because the actual html differs somewhat from mine!

Comment: Honestly, I think the selector is causing the issue. I mean I don't see anything else that might cause it.

Comment: But on the other hand, it worked when I first tried it in the `inspect element` console.

Comment: In that case I would simply play around with test html and your selector expression to see where it's going wrong, like go one expression at a time, e.g. start with #table_results, then add element to the selector to see where it breaks!

Comment: Well the test html worked, but the actual one doesn't. Like wha....

Comment: I guess I will be figuring it out. Thanks for your time tho. :) Anyways, will mark it as Solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, glad to help, hope you get it figured out!!